# While using input type file with inappbrowser it crashes in iOS, what could be the reason?

Tags: ios, file, cordova, input, inappbrowser

I am adding `main.html` `index.js` and `config.xml` file for plugin versions and phonegap versions and yes, I am making builds online using `build.phonegap.com`.

Even I tried to verify with `gmail.com`; in that also attach file function is not working I have confirmed that.

It is compulsory form me to use in app browser as I need to load an external website using phonegap wrapper. I could use iframe but it's not working in iOS.

Here is my **index.html**:

```
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
                <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
                <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
                <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

                <title>experiment</title>

            </head>
            <body>

                         Select a file: <input type="file" name="img">



            </body>

        </html>
```

Here is my **index.js**:

```
        var app = {
            // Application Constructor
            initialize: function() {
                this.bindEvents();
            },
            // Bind Event Listeners
            //
            // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
            // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
            bindEvents: function() {
                document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
            },
            // deviceready Event Handler
            //
            // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
            // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
            onDeviceReady: function() {
                app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
            },
            // Update DOM on a Received Event
            receivedEvent: function(id) {
                var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
                var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
                var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

                listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
                receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');


                console.log('Received Event: ' + id);

                var ref = window.open('main.html', ' _blank', 'location=no,hidden=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no');
                ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert("load start");
                });
                ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert("load stop");
                ref.show(); });
            }
        };
```

Here is my **config.xml**:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.phonegap.helloworld"
        version   = "1.0.0">

    <name>Hello World</name>

    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>

    <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>


    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>


    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->

    <!-- Plugins -->

    <!-- Core plugins -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" version="1.0.0" source="npm"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" />


    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"      gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"              gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg"      gap:platform="winphone" />

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
    <string>100</string>
    </gap:config-file>


    <access origin="*"/>

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

</widget>
```

Comment: solved.. I was using old version of browser to remove the default spinner by inappbrowser